# Where does netsh load resource strings from?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, netsh

as far as I know, there is no netsh equivalent (prior to Windows 8\2012) and netsh must be called directly and output parsed.

Unfortunately, language packs are applied to Netsh, therefore parsing of results is not possible, since result depends on the language.

I'm trying to identify where the resource strings are loaded from (so I could refer to source rather than hardcoding the strings), however I cannot find it.

Any ideas where to look for this? I'm specifically interested in "Base Reachable Time" from "netsh interface ipv4 show interface #" command.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Martin

Comment: As far as I remember Nesh.exe exists since Windows 2000. Why do you put PowerShell tag ?

Comment: Because I actually need to parse it from Powershell using Get-ResourceString:
http://powershell.com/cs/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00.00.01.10.70/dctqyd5u.ps1

And prior to Windows8\2012, there was no way (as far as I know) to get functionality of netsh - now there were new WMI classes introduced

Comment: WMI also exist since W2K.

Comment: WMI doesn't equal to WMI classes (new ones are being added with each release of Windows).

Comment: I haven't words to explain how diffifult it  is to use WMI, I spent more than 6 hours to get a useful program to work. It's a lot easier to use netsh but it have this caveat about the language indefinition.

Answer (score 1):

The resources are usually stored in a MUI file e.g. c:\windows\system32\en-us\netsh.exe.mui.  Of course, the subdir (en-us) will vary based on the OS's default locale.  If I run strings.exe (Sysinternals) on this file I get the following output (abbreviated):

```
83> strings C:\Windows\system32\en-US\netsh.exe.mui

Strings v2.41
Copyright (C) 1999-2009 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.
Uu]
Rich
.rsrc
MUI
MUI
en-US
Ok.
*The following alias was not found: %1!s!.
 The command cannot be executed.
>There is not enough memory available to complete this action.
The following sub-contexts are available:
...
```

This [blog post](http://www.siao2.com/2010/08/11/10048694.aspx) talks about how to extract the resource strings via a p/invoke.

Comment: Hello Keith,

Thanks for reply - .mui was actually my first guess, unfortunately, it seems that netsh.exe is loading this specific string from some other location :(

I remember (few years ago) that Netsh.exe was actually loading some strings from resource file for Windows Firewall, however I cannot find where "Base Reachable Time" comes from :(

Martin